# Unresolved reference: vectorResource and imageResources in Jetpact Compose 1.0.0-beta07

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was using jetpack compose 1.0.0-alpha 11. The below code works.

```
Image(
  imageResource(R.drawable.header),
  contentDescription = null,
  modifier = itemModifier,
  contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
)
```

However in jetpack compose 1.0.0-beta07, `imageResource` and `vectorResource` no longer works.

What's the new way of getting the image resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `1.0.x` you can use the [**`painterResource`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary#painterResource(kotlin.Int)) function:

```
 Image(painterResource(R.drawable.ic_xxxx),"content description")
```

This can load either an instance of `BitmapPainter` or `VectorPainter` for `ImageBitmap` based assets or vector based assets respectively.
This method works with images (PNG or JPG files) or `VectorDrawable` xml assets.

About the usage of [`ImageBitmap.imageResource(R.drawable.header)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ImageBitmap.Companion).imageResource(android.content.res.Resources,kotlin.Int))

> This function is intended to be used for when low-level `ImageBitmap`-specific functionality is required. For simply displaying onscreen, the vector/bitmap-agnostic `painterResource` is recommended instead.

Answer (score 4):

I found we can continue to use `vectorResource` and `imageResource` using the extension of `ImageVector` and `ImageBitmap`

e.g.

```
Image(
  ImageBitmap.imageResource(R.drawable.header),
  contentDescription = null,
  modifier = itemModifier,
  contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
)
```

Comment: Since you are using a `R.drawable` resource , why do you need a `ImageBitmap` instead of a `Painter`?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily access drawable resouces by using painterResource.

```
Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.someVector), contentDescription = null)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works.
However, it returns a different type, i.e `Painter` instead of `ImageBitmap` or `ImageVector`.

Comment: @Elye Use `val imageVector =  ImageVector.vectorResource(R.drawable.vector)` instead.